# Кнопка Back браузера ломает скрипт. Как полечить?

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

В общем, есть скрипт offcanvas окна для корзины/фильтров.

С любой страницы магазина/категории/товара вызываю окно и перехожу по ссылке на страницу корзины, после чего жму в браузере Back, и на `html, body` вешается класс `.noscroll`, как будто окно вызвано и активно, при этом кнопки вызова окна не реагируют.

Если с главной страницы перейти и вернуться — окно активно и работает.

Ссылка на тему: https://maudern.thunder-stores.com/shop/

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  // open shop filters.
  $( document ).on(
    'click touch',
    '.woocommerce .woocommerce-product-loop-header .woocommerce-product-filters span.filters-toggle.offcanvas-filters-toggle',
    function(){
      $( 'html, body' ).addClass( 'noscroll' );
      $( '.offcanvas.offcanvas-shop-filters' ).addClass( 'open' );
      $( '.overlay' ).addClass( 'visible right' ).removeClass( 'delay' );
    }
  );

  // open minicart.
  $( document ).on(
    'click touch',
    '#site-header #secondary-menu-wrapper ul#menu-site-tools > li#shopping-bag-site-tool',
    function(){
      $( 'html, body' ).addClass( 'noscroll' );

      if ( $( document ).find( '#site-header' ).hasClass( 'search-open' ) ) {
        // close search form.
        $( '#site-header #secondary-menu-wrapper ul#menu-site-tools > li#search-site-tool' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $( '.overlay' ).removeClass( 'visible' );

        setTimeout(
          function() {
            $( '#site-header' ).removeClass( 'search-open' );
          },
          200
        );

        setTimeout(
          function() {
            $( '.offcanvas.offcanvas-minicart' ).addClass( 'open' );
            $( '.overlay' ).addClass( 'visible right' );
          },
          800
        );
      } else {
        $( '.offcanvas.offcanvas-minicart' ).addClass( 'open' );
        $( '.overlay' ).addClass( 'visible right' ).removeClass( 'delay' );
      }
    }
  );

  $( document.body ).on(
    'added_to_cart',
    function(){
      $( '#site-header #secondary-menu-wrapper ul#menu-site-tools > li#shopping-bag-site-tool' ).trigger( 'click' );
    }
  );

  // close offcanvas.
  $( document ).on(
    'click touch',
    '.overlay, .offcanvas-close',
    function(){

      $( 'html, body' ).removeClass( 'noscroll' );
      $( '.offcanvas' ).removeClass( 'open' );
      $( '.overlay' ).removeClass( 'visible right left' ).addClass( 'delay' );
    }
  );

  // close offcanvas on link click.
  $( document ).on(
    'click touch',
    '.offcanvas a',
    function(){
      // check for internal links.
      if ( ! $( this ).attr( 'href' ).startsWith( '#' ) &&
      ! $( this ).attr( 'href' ).startsWith( '/' ) &&
      ! $( this ).attr( 'href' ).startsWith( './' ) &&
      ! $( this ).attr( 'href' ).startsWith( '../' ) &&
      ! $( this ).attr( 'href' ).startsWith( $( location ).attr( "href" ) ) &&
      ! $( this ).hasClass( 'remove' ) ) {

        // hide offcanvas.
        $( '.offcanvas' ).hide();
        // hide overlay.
        $( '.overlay' ).hide();
      }
    }
  );

})( jQuery );
```

Вот это не помогло.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', function () { 
    ?>
    <script>
        (function clearNoscroll() { 
            $(window).on('popstate', function() {
              $('html, body').removeClass('noscroll');
            });
        })();
    </script>
<?php 
} );
```

Как полечить такое?